# IIS Rewrite - Creating SEO Friendly URL

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, coldfusion, iis-8, url-rewrite-module

Using IIS v8 and trying to create some SEO Friendly URL's

Current URL is as follows:

```
http://www.domain.com/equipment/flexible/technical.cfm?id=2&title=applications
```

Trying to create:

```
http://www.domain.com/equipment/flexible/2/applications
```

I have the following rule added within web.config - but doesnt seem to be working.

```
<rule name="Product Technical Details">
  <match url="^/equipment/flexible/technical.cfm?([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/equipment/flexible/technical.cfm?id={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your incoming URL is in the format:

```
http://www.domain.com/equipment/flexible/{id}/{title}
```

So, you can modify the rule like this:

```
<rule name="Product Technical Details">
  <match url="^equipment/flexible/technical/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="equipment/flexible/technical.cfm?id={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}" />
</rule>
```

**Edit 1:**

> *domain.com/equipment/flex/technical.cfm?id=2&title=request
>   domain.com/equipment/aero/technical.cfm?id=2&title=basics
>   domain.com/equipment/bulk/technical.cfm?id=2&title=general*
>
> Would I
>   have to create individual rules for each of the above urls? or is it
>   possible to create a single rule for all off the above ?

You can update the rule like this:

```
<rule name="Product Technical Details">
  <match url="^equipment/(flex|aero|bulk)/technical/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="equipment/{R:1}/technical.cfm?id={R:2}&amp;title={R:3}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thank you @beginner this gives me the url http://www.domain.com/equipment/flexible/technical/2/applications instead but i think I can still work with this.  Thanks!

Comment: As a side note we have I have quite a few different urls that require rewriting, but all take on a similar sturcture of two url paramaters.
examples:

http://www.domain.com/equipment/flex/technical.cfm?id=2&title=request

http://www.domain.com/equipment/aero/technical.cfm?id=2&title=basics

http://www.domain.com/equipment/bulk/technical.cfm?id=2&title=general

Would I have to create individual rules for each of the above urls? or is it possible to create a single rule for all off the above ?

Thanks again!

Comment: @Shafiq You can manage that by using a single rule by capturing the parent folder of the requested pages i.e., flex, aero...

Comment: OK.  The parent folder I can grab via coldfusion code.  But can you advice on the rewrite rule?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Brill ... Didnt know you could do that.  Thanks!